# Downloading database data in Notepad format

Tags: database

How do I download the data from a database (phpMyAdmin) in such a away that I can see the data line by line?

I downloaded it but it is all wrapped around and I would be dead by the time I unravelled the 10000 odd records!

Comment: Is your problem Unix vs Windows line terminators?

Comment: ? If you can download your database using phpMyAdmin you can also edit your data using phpMyAdmin.  The download->notepad->probably upload roundtrip I don't understand.

Comment: 1) There's no such thing as *Notepad format*. Notepad is a **text editor**, made for editing **text files**. So the format is **text**. 2) It's simply foolish to download data from your DB, convert it to text to work on it, and then put it back to your DB. You can edit data directly in the DB using phpMyAdmin via SQL statements without all of the other cruft, with much less risk of damaging or corrupting your data or ruining the integrity of constraints and primary keys. Use the DB like it's a DB. What you're doing is like cutting off your arm to trim your fingernails and then sew it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Export the tables one by one as CSV files.  Open them in Excel, or Google sheets.
You could do this for the entire database in a batch, but it's kind of messy.  You're better off exporting one table at a time.

PHPMyAdmin has this capability built in.

I know this is not exactly an answer for Notepad.  But that is simply not the correct way to do what you want.

Comment: I need to work on them in Notepad++ in order to make changes. I said database but should have said table. I already downloaded it as .CSV. But is the problem, it is all in one line and I need it record by record

Comment: In a text editor?  Then you need the info in plain text.  A CSV is plain text.

Comment: Sorry! Start again: After all I can open it in Notepad++, but now I have another problem: all the fiels apper with inverted commas, and each record within brackets. So my next question is how can I get rid of this in Notepad++?

Comment: Not inverted commas! I meant single quotes,

Comment: Uh...  Search and replace?  It's a pretty basic function.

Comment: I still think you're making a mistake editing in Notepad, or any other text editor.  Whoever told you that was the requirement doesn't know what the hell they're talking about.  Go with my original plan, if you need to edit outside the PHPMyAdmin environment.